# Using NGINX pod to manage routing inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to route outside traffic to certain nodeports inside my kubernetes cluster for a school project. I know this should be done with an ingress controller or a load balancer but due to some constraints with the academic clusters we are using, we can only use nodeports. Is it possible to use a NGINX pod using the host network to manage this?

Comment: Why not install nginx with a nodeport service? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

you try below any one of the example.

Example 1:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: influxdb
spec:
  containers:
    - name: influxdb
      image: influxdb
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
          hostPort: 8086
```

Example 2:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: influxdb
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: influxdb
      image: influxdb
```

You can reference this link for additional information https://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/